# Git - opening and editing files from other branches

Tags: git

I am working on a project with two git branches - `master` and `alt`.  I have been working on the `alt` branch for a few days to try some things out, but now I want to switch back to working on the `master` branch to test a few things out there (without deleting `alt`).  Of course, I know about using `checkout` to switch between the branches, but what I actually need is the ability to open and edit the `master` branch as it was left a few days ago.  When I `git checkout master` and open the project in Sublime Text, the version of the project that I see is the `alt` version.

How does one not only `checkout` a branch but open and edit the project as it was last left on that branch?

Comment: I would expect Git to _not_ let you checkout the `master` branch if you have done some work in `alt`.  Are you sure you really switched branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use `git checkout master` and then click into sublime text, it will automatically show the updated version. Your question answers itself, as `git checkout` is the only way to do the required task.

Are you using any sublime packages to enhance git?

Comment: You are correct - my apologies, Sublime Text does do this automatically.  My mistake was that I had unsaved changes that hadn't been committed to the `alt` branch.

Answer (score 3):

There two ways you can do this:

1. Commit the changes in `alt` branch and then do `git checkout master`.
2. If you do not want to commit then do `git stash` in `alt` branch and then go to master by doing this: `git checkout master`. Later once you have done the testing in `master`, checkout to `alt` and do `git stash apply`(this would reapply the changes to `alt` branch).

> Each time you do `git stash` it creates a list of changes, which can
>   be checked by `git stash list`. Each item will have an index number to
>   it starting from 0. So if you stash more than once you can reapply a
>   particular stash like this: `git stash apply @stash{<index_no>}`.

You can read more on `git stash` [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing).

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful.  I realize that I had made a mistake, though, which is that I had uncommitted changes on the `alt` branch.  Once I committed them and switched back to `master`, Sublime Text opened the `master` branch files.